# guzzlehttp couldn't resolve host

Tags: laravel, curl, vagrant, guzzle

I have vagrant setup. I have one domain called - test-api.local and This is homestead laravel. WHen I try to access `https://test-api.local/` it works well.

Now I also have another laravel project it's in vagrant to and it's called test-another.local. I can access this into browser too.

Problem: What I want to do is when I connect to test-another.local, this has to connect to test-api.local, get the response from there and get it back to me.

Here is my test-another.local one of the routes.

```
$this->client = new Client(['verify' => false]);
$d = $this->client->get("https://test-api.local/");
return $d;
```

**Error: IT says host cURL error 6: Could not resolve host - test-api.local**

what do I do?

Comment: You need to set your vagrant boxes private networks to use the same subnet https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/private_network.html

Answer (score 0):

Vagrant runs a site inside a VirtualBox virtual machine, which has it's own `/etc/hosts` file for "local" domain. Probably you need to edit this file inside the virtual machine and add an appropriate record for `test-api.local` there.

Try to open `/etc/hosts` on your host machine and copy the entry for `test-api.local` into the virtual machine.